# Unable to auto assign Document properties from Document Set shared columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary, sharepoint-documents

I have a SharePoint document library I am working on. It has a list of document sets. Each document set has a few fields that are marked as "Shared" so that they can be inherited by the documents inside.

When I upload a document inside a form opens and all the fields on the form are pre-filled with the shared values of the corresponding columns. But when I use create document from template, it opens the template in the corresponding Office application but the document property fields are empty and not read-only which is against the requirements of this project. I require them to be synced and filled exactly like when a document is uploaded.

There is one thing though. The user can fill any value he wants in those fields and they will still be saved a synced copy from parent in the library discarding what the user filled in, which is good, but why not show those values up in the document in the first place?

Anyone has experience in handling this please help. I have searched a lot on the internet but either my keywords are wrong or no one has had this problem before.

SharePoint version: 2010 Server

Office version: 2010 Professional

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a simple event reciever, which fire on itemadded. It would then go back up the tree to find the document set. Capture which properties are marked as shared. Adjust the item that is being added to force the values.

Probably 8 lines of code

Comment: Is there no "out of the box" way to accomplish this? My requirements are strictly confined to SharePoint included features with minimum possible customization and no coding.